# How do I create a subset of an xml file or filter out child nodes of an xml file using powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, xslt

I have an xml file like the following

```
...
<body>
  <node1 attribute1="attr1">
     <child1 attribute1="A">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child1>
     <child2 attribute1="B">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child2>
  </node1>
  <node2 attribute1="attr1">
     <child1 attribute1="A">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child1>
     <child2 attribute1="B">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child2>
  </node2>
</body>
```

I would like to use powershell to create another xml file with just all the child1 nodes or just all the child2 nodes.

I've read something about xslt transforms as well but not familiar with that either.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution, not using xpath but working with string replacement and regular expression. It's efficient and can be written in one line (have a look at the last line).

My file is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <node1 attribute1="attr1">
     <child1 attribute1="A">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child1>
     <child2 attribute1="B">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child2>
  </node1>
  <node2 attribute1="attr1">
     <child1 attribute1="A">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child1>
     <child2 attribute1="B">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child2>
  </node2>
</body>
```

I first load it in a var (`$a`) as a single string using the `-raw` param of `Get-Content`.

```
$a =Get-Content 'D:\temp\M4.xml' -raw
```

Then I use a regex to replace the node you don't want by nothing.

```
$a -replace '(?sm)     <child1.*?Child1>\r\n','' | set-content 'd:\temp\filewithoutchild1.xml'
```

The result is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <node1 attribute1="attr1">
     <child2 attribute1="B">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child2>
  </node1>
  <node2 attribute1="attr1">
     <child2 attribute1="B">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child2>
  </node2>
</body>
```

The trick in the regex is with (?sm) you will find a good explanation [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

Using one line :

```
(Get-Content 'D:\temp\M4.xml' -raw) -replace '(?sm)     <child1.*?Child1>\r\n','' | set-content 'd:\temp\filewithoutchild1.xml'
```

---

**Edited on 05/05/2015**

So now the working file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <node1 attribute1="attr1">
     <child1 attribute1="A">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child1>
     <child1 attribute1="B">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child1>
     <child1 attribute1="C">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child1>   
  </node1>
  <node2 attribute1="attr1">
     <child1 attribute1="A">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child1>
     <child1 attribute1="B">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child1>
     <child1 attribute1="C">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child1>   
  </node2>
</body>
```

Here is the code that allow you to select only the sub nodes you need. Although it thechnicaly works, I'am not so proud of it.

I use the same way, but this time I loop removing tags while it only exists the one you need. In the example I keep "C" country code.

```
Clear-Host

$a =Get-Content 'D:\temp\M.xml' -raw 
$reg = [regex]'(?sm)(  <child1.*?</child1>)'
$tagMatches = $reg.Matches($a)

$blRemoved = $true
while ($blRemoved)
{
  $tagMatches = $reg.Matches($a)
  $blRemoved = $false
  foreach ($tagMatch in $tagMatches)
  {
    if ($tagMatch.value -notlike "*`"C`"*")
    {
      Write-Host $tagMatch.value
      $a = $a.Remove($tagMatch.Index,$tagMatch.Length+4)
      $blRemoved = $true
      break
    }
  }
}

$a
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you help me to do the opposite in this example. My example is a poor example. I should have added more children in the example.  So the example should be lots of children elements, and I only want one of the children in the resulting xml file.

Comment: Can you be more acurate and give more detail about the tags you want to suppress ?

Comment: So in each node I have lots of child tags and I only want to keep one of them. With your solution, you filter out the one you don't want out of 2 tags so it's easy to exclude the one, but if I have many it will be easier to keep the one.  I don't have enough room on this comment, will continue on next one.

Comment: Ex. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <node1 attribute1="attr1">
     <child2 attribute1="B">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child2>
     ...
     <child50 attribute1="...">
         <grandchild>
          </grandchild>
     </child50>
  </node1>
  <node2 attribute1="attr1">
     <child2 attribute1="B">
       <grandchild>
       </grandchild>
     </child2>
     ...
     <child50 attribute1="...">
         <grandchild>
          </grandchild>
     </child50>
  </node2>
  ...
  <node50 ...>
   ...
  </node50>
</body>

Comment: It can be simple if you are able to establish a list of all the tags you want to suppress. can you share an original file ? Are all the possible child present under node1 ? this should also help ?

Comment: How about this? replace the elements between the body tag with a lot of elements in the following post. So the xml will contain a lot of <tu id="*"> elements. So I want to have an ending xml file which has all the tu elements and only one of the tuv elements under it and all other tuv elements filtered out.

Comment: <tu id="A">
    <tuv lang="EN-US">
        <seg></seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv lang="FR-FR">
        <seg></seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv lang="CS-CZ">
        <seg></seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv lang="DE-DE">
        <seg></seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv lang="ES-ES">
        <seg></seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv lang="HU-HU">
        <seg></seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv lang="IT-IT">
        <seg></seg>
    </tuv>
    ...
    <tuv lang="ZH-TW">
        <seg></seg>
    </tuv>
</tu>

Comment: Now I understand what you need.

Comment: I'm glad I've cleared things up. Do you think you can help me with what I need? Thank you!

Comment: @Victor, I do the job :o)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has a built-in Cmdlet called `Select-XML` that is perfectly suited for this task.  Assuming you've got this XML file stored in a file called .\SomeFile.xml, and want to get all of the nodes called 'Child1'

```
$xml = [xml](gc T:\SomeFile.xml)
$xml | Select-Xml -XPath //child1

Node   Path        Pattern 
----   ----        ------- 
child1 InputStream //child1
child1 InputStream //child1
```

You use XPath's notation of '//' to say 'give me all of the nodes that end with this' to grab the children.  If you want to do something more complex, you'll need to look into some XPath reference.

Here's a quick reference guide.  Be sure to check out ['Selecting Nodes' here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), for some more XPath Goodness..

[image]

Comment: FoxDeploy, thanks for the help. I've learned a lot just from your example, however, JPBlac's answer is more what I'm looking for.

Comment: Great! I'm happy you found a good answer. I'll leave mine here in case someone else stumbles upon this post and could use my approach.